# Cordova - Parsing of "config.xml" Fails

Tags: android, xml, cordova

I am currently unable to install Crosswalk and/or run builds using Cordova because Cordova keeps looking for the config.xml file in the wrong location.

**Steps to reproduce:**

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Error: Unhandled "error" event. (Parsing 
/cordova/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml failed)
```

**Note: this path doesn't exist.**

The correct path according to the directory/file structure should be:

```
/cordova/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml
```

**Is there any way to change the path that Cordova looks for the config.xml file?**

---

Cordova: 8.0.0

Gradle 4.4.1

Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Node: 8.9.3

NPM: 5.6.0

Answer (score 3):

In my case I did the following:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android --save
ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0 --save
```

Comment: ...and what happened? Please describe a little bit more about how this solves the problem.

Comment: This is a downgrade of cordova-android. I assume that in cordova-android 7.x.x (which support Cordova 8), the files have moved around. The error will be fixed, since this leans on the old structure of your project. However, considering this is a downgrade, I don't think this is the preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

I made a fix [here](https://github.com/kaidokert/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/commit/3e3448af982e98071f65ee836f9eca8b4451a3bf), seems to work. Not sure if cordova or cordova-android have recently changed the locations

Comment: Great! Thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

I incorrectly added GTM resource-file into config.xml like this:

```
<platform name="android">
     <resource-file src="GTM-XXXXXXX.json" target="assets/containers/GTM-XXXXXXX.json" />
```

I knew because I noticed after saving config.xml, the preview of the file changed to unknown.
So, I just removed

```
<platform name="android">
```

and moved

```
<resource-file src="GTM-XXXXXXX.json" target="assets/containers/GTM-XXXXXXX.json" />
```

to under

```
<engine name="android"/>
```

and the problem solved.

Comment: thanks it is working fine in android. How to do for ios. For phonegap build it is not working. please advice

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an logical error in config.xml Check your config.xml whether are you making any logical mistakes in describing your resources.